Title of Documentary about a guy spending his time pranking society
There was this guy who spent most of his life working shitty jobs and putting all his energy into pranking people. And his daughter made a documentary about him.
Among his jokes were the following:  

He started a society against red haired people and protested in front of a Wendy's against their logo and actually found people who joined him.
He claimed he would only eat hair and even got on TV giving an interview about it, eating a sandwich, claiming it was made from nothing but hair.

Does anyone have any idea what his name was or what the title of the movie is?

This might be a long shot, but there was a comedian named Alan Abel who was known for putting on big hoaxes, and his daughter made a documentary about them. 

In 2004, his daughter Jenny Abel along with Jeff Hockett made a documentary film of Abel's life called Abel Raises Cain, which played at the Boston Independent Film Festival and the 2005 Slamdance Film Festival where it won first prize for Best Documentary. It has been released on DVD, and is also on Hulu. As of June 2013 it is not available on Netflix.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Abel_

However, in the list of hoaxes on his website (http://www.alanabel.com/alan_abel_media_pranks_hoaxes.htm) I don't see any mention of hair-related pranks.
In 2007, the Improv Everywhere group put on a protest of redheads in front of Wendy's: http://improveverywhere.com/2007/07/24/redheads/
Possible that you have them mixed together?

You are right - That is it!
But do watch the movie, he did a Wendys hoax!
